# sizing with pixels swift spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, size, skspritenode, cgsize

I have a total newbie question with swift. I am running into an obstacle when sizing my nodes. I would like to size my nodes like this...

```
 player.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
```

This comes out looking great, but when I run it on an Ipad, all the proportions are off. so I end up having to size my nodes like this...

```
 player.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width / 10, height: self.frame.height / 10)
```

is this just how you have to do it if you want it to look good on every device? or is there a way to size it with pixels? Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: are you managing different graphics for IPad ? if yes then create size proportion to your frame size. otherwise you need to scale up , like you have to multiplier that would be multiplied with framesize for ipad.

Comment: How are you handling your scale mode?  There is almost no reason to use this type of math (`player.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width / 10, height: self.frame.height / 10)`) with Sprite kit.  It could lead to a lot of bugs.  I am assuming if player takes 10% of the screen on an iPhone, you want it to take 10% of the screen on an iPad, is this correct?

Comment: yes that is corect. Do you know an easier way of scaling? I currently do not have a scale mode such as .aspectFill etc...

Comment: sorry, that was wrong. In my gameViewController.swift the scale mode is set to .aspectFill

Comment: Right, you are forced to pick a scale mode.  If you are doing aspect fill, then you should not be scaling at all, the library will do it for you.

Comment: thanks for the help